# Web service Listener for soap messages in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, listener

I want to create a listener for soap messages. Can this be done using a web service in c sharp?
The soap messages contain xml data inside the soap body. I want the web service listener to be able to extract this xml data from the soap message.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Services are SOAP listeners, but abstract away all the messy XML.

If you want to get into the message and read or modify it, you can do so in WCF using custom behaviours with message inspectors and interceptors:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751495.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your solution.I used the message inspector(IDispatchMessageInspector) and was able to inspect the SOAP messages on the web service side.